# Linear Algebra: Residual $A x - b$

Tags: linear-algebra, octave

I'm doing a course on Applied Linear Algebra. Which, for the most part, is about applications in Octave, so there isn't much about the happenings behind a lot of the mechanics of everything.

I'm faced with the statement: 
"You can use the condition number to estimate the accuracy at which Octave solves for $x$ in $A x = b$. **"First, we define the residual which is $A x - b$."**

And I'm battling to understand this residual "$A x - b$". 
I'm trying to find some answers as to what this residual is and what to do with it.

Any help or reading material I can explore will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By numerical solution of $Ax=b$ we obtain $\bar x$.

If $\bar x$ was an exact solution it should be $$A\bar x=b \implies A\bar x-b=0$$

since we always have  some kind of numerical error or approximation we have a residual (vector) that is

$$r=A \bar x-b\neq 0$$

We can extimate the error by the norm |r|.

Comment: Okay I understand now. Thank you for the explanation. My reading material totally failed in explaining anything meant this. Thanks so much!

Comment: @amateurjustin You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m{\times}n}$, as a procedure to move point (or vector) x in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a point b in  $\mathbb{R}^m$, denoted $Ax=b$. Usually, $m=n$, meaning the matrix is square.

An example would be to have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3{\times}3}$ and x in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which can be considered our space. The center of the sun could be defined as the origin i.e. $(0, 0, 0)$. If we compute $Ax=b$ , we compute how the matrix $A$ moves point $x$ in space to $b$. The trajectory of Heavy Falcon can then be described as $x_{i+1}=Ax_{i}$ and $x_{0}$ would then be Cape Canaveral.

A linear system of equation $Ax=b$ can be reformulated as: given the "moving procedure" $A$ and my final position $b$, where did I start?

The residual is the difference between $Ax_{guess}$ and $b$, meaning we guess that we started from $x_{guess}$ and since we know the "moving procedure" $A$, we end up at $Ax_{guess}$. If your $x_{guess}$ is correct, we end up at $b$. Usually the distance (euclidean norm) is used: $||Ax_{guess}-b||_2$.

Comment: I can't mark two answers as correct, unfortunately, but I do love your answer!

Comment: It's really a perfect description of an application and how to imagine the workings. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: And this explains a lot. A smaller residual (being the norm in this case) means that the _xguess_ is closer to the truth, am I right in saying this?

Comment: Yes, if your residual, $||Ax_{guess}-b||_2$, is small, that means your $x_{guess}$ is close to the actual $x$. (most often you don't know the actual $x$).